# VB.NET Timers on Server-side

Tags: vb.net, timer, timeout, synchronous

I have a situation where I'm trying to, from a client-side piece, call off to a server-side piece.

I need to do this synchronously.  On my server-side code, though, I'm calling off to another piece of code, which I want to have a maximum of, say, 10 seconds to return a value.

If I don't have a response within 10 seconds, I want to force my own server piece to set my result equal to 0, and return to the client.

Here's what I have on my server-side code so far:

```
   Public Function GetWebResult(ByVal inputParameter As Object) As WebReturnObject Implements IWebInterface.GetWebResult
      Dim result As New WebReturnObject
      Dim webItem As WebItem = Nothing

      _timer = New Timers.Timer
      AddHandler _timer.Elapsed, AddressOf HandleTimerElapsed
      _timer.Interval = 10000 '10 Seconds'
      _timer.AutoReset = False

      _timer.Start()
      webItem = GetAWebItem(inputParameter)
      _timer.Stop()

      result = webItem
      Return result
   End Function

   Private Sub HandleTimerElapsed(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs) Handles _timer.Elapsed
      'result.HasTimedOut = True'
      'result.Value = 0'
      'How do I then get back into GetWebResult?'
   End Sub
```

I realize this code is not functional.  The problem is that I'm unsure how I would go about getting back into `GetWebResult` to set the appropriate return values before it is sent back to the client.

I've already Google'd this problem, and results were scant.  The best resources I was able to find were the MSDN documentation on the [Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=VS.90%29.aspx#Y700) class, but even that isn't terribly useful given my situation.

If anyone has any links, suggestions, etc., I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the method asynchronously with a timeout (10 seconds) you'll be back in `GetWebResult` irrespective of the method call completion, then you could return from there. [Sample here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37365/Calling-Method-Asynchronously-With-A-Timeout.aspx)